# Don't scroll on element resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, typescript

I'm making an angular directive that hides element a when the user scrolls on element b. It works fine, but I can't figure out this behaviour:

[image]

It might be hard to tell, but essentially when you scroll to the bottom the scroll bar expands because element a sits above element b, so essentially the thing I'm scrolling on has more space available. After that, I'm not sure why it scrolls up. Here's a gif of the full page if that makes it any clearer:

[image]

My directive is written in typescript (angular version 1.5.7 NOT 2.x), I'll work on translating it to javascript but in the interest of getting this question out there as quickly as possible here's the ts:

```
interface IScope extends ng.IScope {
        showHeader: boolean;
    }
    export class IncodeHideHeaderDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        restrict = "AE";
        require: "ngModel";
        scope: Object;
        replace = true;
        link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn | ng.IDirectivePrePost;
        oldy: number;
        justScrolled = false;


        constructor() {
            const self = this;
            this.link = (scope: IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) =>
            {
                element.bind("scroll",
                    () => {
                        if (element[0].scrollTop > self.oldy) {
                            console.log("collapsing");
                            scope.$eval("showHeader=false");
                        }
                        else if (element[0].scrollTop < self.oldy)
                        {
                            console.log("expanding");
                            scope.$eval("showHeader=true");
                        }
                        self.oldy = element[0].scrollTop;
                    }
                );

                element.bind("load",
                () => {
                    console.log(scope);
                    this.oldy = element[0].scrollTop;
                });
            };
        }






        public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            const directive = () => new IncodeHideHeaderDirective();
            return directive;
        }


    }

    angular.module("incode.module")
        .directive("ixHeader", incode.directives.label.IncodeHideHeaderDirective.factory());
```

pretty basic stuff. How do I get the scrollbar to stop doing this weird stuff?
Here's [a fiddle demonstrating the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/e8j938g8/1/).

Comment: If you make a MVCE in jsfiddle, it will be easier to find the problem.

Comment: I will when I get off work, it's too much of a hassle to extract from the complex jumble of a template when I have official things to do.

Comment: @rm4 Got that fiddle ya ordered

Answer (score 0):

That's not an Angular answer, but why not just remove your header bar from the flow by making it `position: fixed` (or `absolute`) ? It would not cause the reflow of the main contents, and you would have none of the issues you are experiencing.

```
.slideUp {
    /* ... */
    position: fixed;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8j938g8/3/

Comment: Because it cuts off content on the card. (https://i.gyazo.com/2646f80bb6038ab8bc26421400edc882.png)
I actually used to do that, but then I'd need a spacer div or a margin, which reproduces the same problem, just with a different element.